# AngularJS blank default in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element with six options, the first being a blank option:

```
<select name="method-rcvd" class="form-control" ng-model="workRequest.ReceiveMethod" required >
    <option value="" ng-selected="true"></option>
    <option value="1">Phone</option>
    <option value="2">Email</option>
    <option value="3">Fax</option>
    <option value="4">Mail</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
```

On the scope is the object property bound to this select:

```
$scope.workRequest.ReceiveMethod = "";
```

For some reason, the select ALWAYS defaults to "Phone", instead of blank. I want it to default to blank. When I remove the model binding it works, so I know it has something to do with that, but it needs to be bound. This seems to me that it should be relatively straightforward, but I am having a very difficult time getting this simple thing working.

When I spit out the value of ReceiveMethod below the select:

```
Receive Method: {{workRequest.ReceiveMethod}}
```

It always defaults to "1". How can I get this to default to the first option, the blank option?

Thanks.

Comment: Switch to ng-options http://plnkr.co/edit/77kSRwz2KGDc8VYtxEeP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a default value in the controller?

What happens if you set default value to `0` instead of `''`?

That should work but something must be setting another value on `workRequest.ReceiveMethod`

Comment: Yes, I'm setting a default value in the controller to an empty string. The problem with setting it to zero is I'm using form validation, making this drop down required, and a value of zero validates the element, when it should not.

Comment: If you set it to `0` does it still select `1` on page load or does it stay as the default though?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the ng-init directive, like so:

```
<select name="method-rcvd" class="form-control"
        ng-model="workRequest.ReceiveMethod"
        ng-init="workRequest.ReceiveMethod = ''" required >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Phone</option>
    <option value="2">Email</option>
    <option value="3">Fax</option>
    <option value="4">Mail</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
```

You also don't need the

> ng-selected="true"

in the first (blank) option.